# How to access Oracle Data Base from Android Application. 

Tags: java, android, web-services, client-server, restful-authentication

Android application which will show data from **external Data Base(Oracle)** in the database server .It can be possible only with **web services(RESTful)**,so i decided to develop a web services in Java/Java EE itself.
I dont want go with PHP or some other technologies.Pls suggest me to proceed this.

Comment: I googled about it.I found only RESTful is supportable for Android,but SOAP is purely on XML.Android can't get XML format responses.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the web service. Is it just RESTful XML? JAX-WS? JSON? Etc.Either way it should be as easy as calling out with an HTTP socket and parsing the response.

To create a web-service follow the below link

[RESTful Web Services](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html)

using Using HTTPClient

```
public static String hitService(String host, int port, String path, String postBody) throws IOException {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host, port);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(path);
        HttpEntity results = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(target, get);
            results = response.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(results);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Web Service Failure");
        } finally {
            if (results!=null)
                try {
                    results.consumeContent();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // empty, Checked exception but don't care
                }
        }
    }
```

[Android Cookbook example](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=79)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually im having knowledge in JSP,Servlets and Struts.Now i want to design a web services to access the Oracle DB in DB Server from Android application.I want to know the way to develop the Web service.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB is quite popular nowadays, it works great with Android. [Watch this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RdcKWYGqig)

> Apache CouchDB is a document-oriented database that can be queried and indexed in a MapReduce fashion using JavaScript. CouchDB also offers incremental replication with bi-directional conflict detection and resolution.
>
> CouchDB provides a RESTful JSON API than can be accessed from any environment that allows HTTP requests. There are myriad third-party client libraries that make this even easier from your programming language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RestClient {

    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    private String url;

    private int responseCode;
    private String message;

    private String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public RestClient(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {
        switch(method) {
            case GET:
            {
                //add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for(NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),”UTF-8″);
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```