# Connecting to an oracle database using web service

Tags: php, android, oracle

I have an android application that should connect to a database to retrieve some data to be shown on the screen.

The only method I know is to connect to mySQL using local host.

But how to connect to a real oracle database using the web service which is written in PHP.

Please help me since I didn't find any related information like this.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964350/how-to-access-oracle-data-base-from-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is works for me in past, I hope its works for you too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/